# Struct Array fill with Void Function

Tags: c

Trying to pass struct array to void function and get the array filled with some calculation but i got that [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct point' from type 'double'

```
#define P 45
struct point {
 double x, y;
};
struct point vals[P];

void calculate_values(double l, double r)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<P;i++)
    {
        vals[i]=(l+i)*(l-r)/(P-1);
    }
}
in main
    calculate_values(-5, 5.0);
```

Comment: In `vals[i] = (l+i)*(l-r)/(P-1);` you are trying to assign the calculation result to the structure. You could do something like `vals[i].x = (l+i)*(l-r)/(P-1);`.

Comment: WTF is this?  `in main calculate_values(-5, 5.0);`

`in` is not a valid c keyword.  `main` should have parens and curly-brackets.

Answer (score 2):

This line here tries to assign a single number to `vals[i]`

`vals[i]=(l+i)*(l-r)/(P-1);`

`vals[i]` is an instance of point, which whould need 2 numbers and to be assigned differently.  eg.

`vals[i].x=(l+i)*(l-r)/(P-1);`

Comment: inside the the function i add struct point x; and write it as you said but now got different error that vals is undeclared